# reverse FKG type inequality for slightly correlated Gaussian vectors

Tags: pr.probability, measure-concentration

Let $X$ be a $m$-dimensional Gaussian vector, and $Y$ a $q$-dimensional Gaussian vector, for some $m,q\geq 1$. Assume that the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are centred and have unit variance. Assume that $E X_i Y_j \leq \mu$ for any $i,j$, for some $\mu< 1$.

Is there a constant $C_{\mu,m,q}$ such that for every Borel $A,B$,
$$P(X\in A,Y\in B)\leq C_{\mu,m,q} P(X\in A)P(Y\in B)?$$

It would imply $E \varphi(X)\psi(Y)\leq C_{\mu,m,q} E\varphi(X)E\psi(Y)$ for (say) nonnegtive $\varphi,\psi$.

The inequality "feels" right, it works if $X$ and $Y$ are both uni-dimensional.

it looks like some of the measure concentration inequalities verified by the Gaussian, but I don't manage to find a proof and actually such a proof should be simple given the simplicity of the inequality (it might actually mean that it is completely wrong). Anyone could share ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this formulation, it still isn't true.
Take $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$i.i.d standard Gaussian. Take $\{Y_i\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$ i.i.d. standard Gaussian. Take $Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i/\sqrt{n}$. Then $|EX_i Y_j|\leq 1/\sqrt{n}$ for any $i,j$.
Fix $D\subset R$ measurable.
Take $A=\{\sum X_i/\sqrt{n}\in D\}$ and $B=\{Y_n\in D\}$. Then the left side of your inequality is simply $P(Y_n\in D)$ while the right side is $C_{\mu,n} P(Y_n\in D)^2$.
Now take a sequence $D_m$ so that $P(Y_n\in D_m)\to_{m\to\infty} 0$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. My problem is actually to compute $$E|X_1 X_2 Y_1 Y_2|^{-\alpha}$$ where $\alpha\in (0,1)$, the $X_i,Y_j$ are as above for some $\mu<1$, and $X_1,X_2$ have correlation $r$, as well as $Y_1,Y_2$. I am looking for a good bound as $r\to 0$. Would you have any references (or ideas?). Thanks

Comment: You can then explicitly write the 4 variables in terms of 4 independent standard normals. Then optimize constants.